# How to match all groups of text that contain a specific word in a specific line?

Tags: regex, notepad++, substring, word-boundary

I'm trying to create a regular expression to sift through information in a text file (Notepad++), but only if the character has a "the" in the name.

My current expression: `\\{[\r\n]+id:(.\*?)+name:\s+(\bthe\b)(.*?)[\r\n]\\}`

```
{
id:     1
locID:  A
tStart: 17:10:00
tEnd:   17:35:00
name:   the man 45
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     2
locID:  A
tStart: 17:11:00
tEnd:   17:12:00
name:   Frank
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     3
locID:  A
tStart: 17:11:00
tEnd:   17:14:00
name:   Frank
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     4
locID:  B
tStart: 17:51:00
tEnd:   17:56:00
name:   the woman 2
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     5
locID:  A
tStart: 17:11:00
tEnd:   16:11:00
name:   the man with the golden gun
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     6
locID:  C
tStart: 17:11:00
tEnd:   17:11:00
name:   the woman with the dragon tattoo
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     7
locID:  A
tStart: 17:15:00
tEnd:   17:15:00
name:   Jo
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
```

What I want is to only get

```
{
id:     1
locID:  A
tStart: 17:10:00
tEnd:   17:35:00
name:   the man 45
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     4
locID:  B
tStart: 17:51:00
tEnd:   17:56:00
name:   the woman 2
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     5
locID:  A
tStart: 17:11:00
tEnd:   16:11:00
name:   the man with the golden gun
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
{
id:     6
locID:  C
tStart: 17:11:00
tEnd:   17:11:00
name:   the woman with the dragon tattoo
text:   Lorum Ipsum
}
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do to skip the rest of the line?

My current setup returns everything, and `Frank id:2` `Frank id:3` `the woman 2 id:4`.

Thanks mickmackusa.

Solution: {[^}]*name:[^}]*\bthe\b[^}]*\}

Comment: Show source from where you analyse data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negated character classes `[^}]` speed everything up and avoid getting snagged on newline characters.  The `*` can be greedy because they will be halted on `name:`, `the`, and `}`.

Pattern ([Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/QxpW5D/4)):

```
{[^}]*name:[^}]*\bthe\b[^}]*}
```

Edit (escaping the curly bracket version):

```
\{[^}]*name:[^}]*\bthe\b[^}]*\}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works!

The only caveat is that your answer accidentally left out a slash due to the autoformatting {[^}]*name:[^}]*\bthe\b[^}]*\}